# Is it possible to run Android on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arm-processors, hardware-requirements

With smartphones and the Raspberry Pi both being ARM devices, is it possible to run Android on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yeah ofc.. Check this out... [Google Android on your Raspberry Pi with emteria OS](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/android-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you happen to have a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB or 8GB, you can try out an unofficial build of LineageOS 17.1 for Raspberry Pi 4. One of my favorite YouTubers [Leepspvideo](https://www.youtube.com/user/leepspvideomade) made a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/3i2h9JgPPME) on installing Android 10 LineageOS on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two routes for running Android on Raspberry Pi. You need a Pi 3 or later for both of them:

## Non-commercial

KonstKANG provides a variety of images, but the RPi-specific drivers included are limited to non-commercial use, presumably by the author. [Raspberry Tips](https://raspberrytips.com/android-raspberry-pi-4/) has an article on the installation process, as does [BeeBom](https://beebom.com/how-install-android-raspberry-pi/).

### [Rasperry Pi 3](https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi3/)

- LineageOS Android 7.1 to Android 10.

### [Raspberry Pi 4 (and 400)](https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/)

- AOSP Android 12L to 14
- LineageOS for Android 9 to 13 and Android TV 9 to 13.

### [Raspberry Pi 5](https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi5/)

- AOSP Android 14

### Other hardware

KonstKANG also provides TWRP images, and a variety of Android-related images for older devices.

## Commercial

Emteria provides commercial support for Android for kiosk and IoT applications, but has a free starter account that does not time out, clearly as a sales and goodwill generator. They provide a [user guide](https://emteria.com/lp/raspberry-pi-imager-android) for installing AOSP Android with their drivers (up to Android 14) using the Raspberry Pi Imager application. [Little Bird Electronics](https://littlebirdelectronics.com.au/guides/32/run-android-on-raspberry-pi) also has a guide.

The limit on the free account is that it is limited to three devices. Emteria also don't provide all versions of Android: currently, they seem to offer [versions 7, 11, 13 and 14](https://emteria.com/release-notes).

### Other hardware

Emteria also support [various other SBCs](https://emteria.com/supported-hardware), plus [Intel NUCs](https://emteria.com/lp/intel-android-celadon) via [Intel Celadon](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/topic-technology/open/celadon/overview.html). The latter is a route to running Android on x86 and x86-64 hardware, should you want to.